# Place numbers 1 through 9 in boxes (☐☐×☐=☐☐+☐☐=☐☐)

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

So recently I was scrolling through Youtube when I came across [this](https://youtu.be/vlPSlDf6fnQ?si=XT6F0qyHyJ1XON1U) video from MindYourDecisions that was about solving a legendary math puzzle.

The puzzle:

> Place the numbers 1 through 9 in the following boxes such that
>
> ```
>  ☐☐
>  x☐
>  ---
>  ☐☐
> +☐☐
>  ---
>  ☐☐
> ```
>
> Each number can only be used once.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqo0T.png) is the thumbnail of the Youtube video for anyone who wants to see what it looks like:

[image]

Now, I recognized this puzzle as one that I have been struggling to solve on and off for over a decade, and that is bad because I still have not managed to solve this.

---

#### What I can really easily deduce

---

1. If we have `9` in the topmost box in the left column, then only if we multiply by `1` will we be able to satisfy the condition that we have a 2-digit number multiplied by a 1-digit number that is then equal to a 2-digit number. But, this leads to a contradiction because we have to use every number once.
2. We can use the same logic to show that `9` cannot go in the 2nd and 3rd topmost boxes, because we require that we have 2 2-digit numbers being added to each other that is equal to another 2-digit number. However, this cannot be satisfied if we have `9A+BC` (with `AB≠A*B`, but rather representing concatenation).
3. We can also use the same logic as 1) to show that `5`, `6`, `7`, and `8`, also cannot go in the topmost box in the left column.
4. We can notice that since the multiplier cannot be `1`, then it follows that there cannot be a `1` in the second topmost box or the bottom box in the left column.
5. We also cannot have the numbers `8` or `9` as the multiplier, as the minimum value given from any multiplication would result in 96. We can also probably eliminate `6` and `7` from being the multiplier, although I'm not too sure if that would be correct to do.

So [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm4I7.png) is what I have done so far (a blue number means that I am 100% sure it does not go there, a red number means that I am pretty (but not 100%) sure that it could not go there):

[image]

---

However, I am actually unsure about how I would deduce logically (by hand) where the numbers go, so my question is:

#### What should I do to actually solve this?

<sub>Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention that I am looking for a logical way to hand-solve this.</sub>

Comment: Without [tag:no-computers] it's trivial to brute force. Do you just want the numerical solution, or are you specifically after a logical way to hand-solve this?

Comment: @fljx I am after a logical way to hand-solve this, sorry for not specifying. I'll quickly edit if that's okay

Comment: Does the video not contain the solution?

Comment: @ACB Probably does (MindYourDecisions' videos always contain a problem along with an answer), but I was just wanting to try this on my own, since this is a math puzzle that I have been trying to solve since elementary school.

Comment: FYI, the video's solution method is not elegant, as it was essentially testing a huge number of cases, only one of which leads to a solution, to the point where one is just emulating a computer's brute force search.

Comment: You also can't have `5`s in the top three spots of the right column.

Comment: FWIW case bashing to death is a kind of logic. Some "higher-level logic" can help you reduce the amount of work, but I believe you'll need to weed through at least some tens of cases in the end.

Comment: @loopywalt I don't think you can put the 5 anywhere in the units column (a unit 5 in the multiplicand/multiplier requires another 5 in at least one of the products, and vice-versa).

Comment: @fljx Products? I see only one product (in row 3), so I do not see why there couldn't be a 5 at the end of row 4 or row 5. Am I missing something?

Comment: @loopywalt You're right. For some reason I misread the entire thing as a long multiplication summing two products to a final answer (but that would require a two-digit multiplier, and the answer would never be only two digits). Not sure what I was thinking :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would focus on the single digit number

> X * (6+)     Total not possible 13*6+24 >98)
>  X * (5 or 1) Last digit in product not available
>  X * 4:
>   X not 19+            Total not possible $19 * 4+23>98$
>    X not 11,14,15 or 16 Last digit in product not available
>    $12*4$                 First digit in product not available
>    $18*4$ ends on 2       Total not possible $18*4+35>98$
>    $13*4 =52$             Total not possible $13*4+67>98$
>  Only $17 * 4$ left to check: Solution! $17*4 =68+25=93$
>
>  X * 3:
>  X * 2:
>  Still a lot of possibilities to check for uniqueness. I don't see an obvious overall smart way to do that.
>  though e.g.:
>  $4?*2 =?? +??=??$ ->
>  $4?*2 =8? +1?=9?$ ->
>  $43*2 =86 +1?=9?$ (6 is only remaining even number) -> no solution with $4?*2$